# How to pass a javascript data to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have code like this:

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="o">
<input type="text" id="end" name="d">
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" hidden="hidden">

<button onclick="calcRoute();" value="/index.php?route=information/mymove" >text</button>

<script>
      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            computeTotalDistance(response);
          } 
        });
      }
      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = total / 1000.
      document.getElementById("total").value = total + " km";
      }
</script>
```

If I use this code for the button:

`<input type="button" value="go" onclick="calcRoute();">` this executes the javascript function, but does not pass the data to another page.

I have also this part in the controller file:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['o'])) {
            $data['o'] = $this->request->post['o'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['d'])) {
            $data['d'] = $this->request->post['d'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['total'])) {
            $data['total'] = $this->request->post['total'];
        }
```

Comment: You should be using something like `ajax` to pass data to another page.

Comment: why not set a cookie ??

Comment: may be you can set a cookie in one page and access it from another ?

Comment: which `other page`? Are you referring to `index.php?route=information/mymove`? For what purpose do you need to pass data to another page?

Comment: You should calculate the `calcRoute()` on that page.

Comment: What specific data do you need to send elsewhere?

Comment: My biggest problem, is the hidden input filed. There is should be filled with the total value from the javascript. And pass to the another page, and display there.

Comment: presumably there is a form and these input elements are within the form?

Comment: Yes the code is start with this <form action="index.php?route=information/mymove" method="post">

Comment: it's not clear at all from your snippet how the redirection happens and if it happens at all, so the questions is how you do redirections here?

Comment: Basically seems, <button onclick="calcRoute();" value="/index.php?route=information/mymove" >text</button> this button does not execute the javascript function.

Comment: did you actually check if the calcRoute is not being executed or it just doesn't do what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to modify the `computeTotalDistance` function so that once all the calculations are complete it will add the total value to the desired hidden input and then submit the form.

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById("total").value = total + " km";

    if( total && document.getElementById("total").value!='' ) document.getElementById("total").parentNode.submit();
}
```

Alternatively another option would be to use this same callback function to send and ajax request to the same endpoint url.

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById("total").value = total + " km";

    /* send the total by ajax to endpoint url */
    ajax.call( this, url, 'total='+total, (r)=>{
        alert(r);
    } );
}


function ajax( url, params, callback ){
    with( new XMLHttpRequest() ){
        onreadystatechange=function(e){
            if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                callback.call( this.response )
            }
        }
        open( 'POST', url, true );
        setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        send( params );
    }
}
```

It was not originally stated that you wished to `view` the total in another page, merely that you wished to send the value to another page. As that is a requirement then ajax, in this case, is not the best option at all - as there is a form it should be submitted as my initially modified function tries to do.

**update:**
Full example, tested and working which emulates what your code is trying to do.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* 
            consider this as "another page" - the form has submitted to here
            and you can see the POST data...
        */
        exit(printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($_POST,true)));
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Route Calculations</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                let _lat = 56.55;
                let _lng = -2.72;
                let _form = document.querySelector( 'form[name="route-plotter"]' );

                let latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( _lat, _lng );
                let options = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                };
                let map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );

                const calcroute=function(){
                    let request = {
                        origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
                        destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections( response );
                            calculatedistance( response );
                        } 
                    });
                };
                const calculatedistance=function(result){
                    let total=0;
                    let route=result.routes[0];
                    route.legs.forEach( leg=>{
                        total+=leg.distance.value;
                    });
                    document.getElementById('total').value=total;
                    _form.submit();
                };

                _form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',calcroute,false)
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <form name='route-plotter' method="post">
            <input type="text" id="start" name="start" value="dundee" />
            <input type="text" id="end" name="end" value="aberdeen" />
            <input type="text" id="total" name="total" hidden="hidden">        
            <button type="button">Go get the distance</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tired you recommendation, but still not working at least the first one seems the hidden input field is does not contain the data. At the second one I don't know how can I display the ajax post on the another page.

Answer (score 0):

A few important things: you need to make this button a proper submit button, you need to make sure it returns callback as opposed to calling the function directly and you need to make sure the callback returns false. This is how to prevent default behaviour which would be sending the form without running the script.

```
<form action="index.php?route=information/mymove" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="o">
    <input type="text" id="end" name="d">
    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" hidden="hidden">        
    <button type="submit" onclick="return calcRoute();">text</button>
</form>

<script>
      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            computeTotalDistance(response);
          } 
        });
        return false;
      }
      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = total / 1000.
      document.getElementById("total").value = total + " km";
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Simply just not working, same like before. The hidden input field is stay empty.

Comment: can you at least check if the function gets called (hint: console.log and debug in the browser) and then make sure if all the services (google, directionsservice ect) are properly initialized and available in the function scope. Cause if they're not it might even fail silently (with no error) and your computeTotalDistances will never get called. Try `use strict` to check that. I can't debug this piece as it is not isolated from the context and you're not showing the context

Comment: if I use this button
<input type="button" value="GO" onClick="calcRoute();">

<div id="total"></div>

with this part of javascript document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100 /1.60934).toFixed(2) + " miles";

Then the total miles or kms is displayed at the id="total" so that is working.

The problem is, the not pass the data to another page.